# Why my hrefs doesn't work properly when i expand my list by using :focus parameter?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with focus parameter in css. My basic problem is, when I click on my href, it expands my list with hrefs which don't work.

When I comment css below, these hrefs all are fine, but they are also enabled when they are invisible.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

li.position {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: powderblue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.sub-menu ul li a {
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}

ul li a:focus + .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

ul li a:focus + .sub-menu ul li a {
    pointer-events: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">click here</a>

        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="position"><a href="https://amazon.com" class="padding">amazon</a></li>
                <li class="position"><a href="https://amazon.com" class="padding">amazon</a></li>
                <li class="position"><a href="https://amazon.com" class="padding">amazon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `:focus` is not a *parameter*, it's a *pseudo class*. Using precise terminology is important in technical matters.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly said the browser should ignore clicks on the links with `pointer-events:none;`

Comment: Yes, but these hrefs don't work when I expand my list if I add this line

Comment: Is there Javascript involved?

Comment: @Kieslof1234 — I know, that is why I said that that line was the problem. You need to remove it.

Comment: @Quentin I deleted this line, but there is still a problem, if You click above href "click here", there are still invisible 3 hrefs

Answer (score 0):

You are using opacity to hide your links. This is not the best way because the links are still there, just invisible.

What you really want to do really hide the links when they shouldn't be visible. I recommend using `display: none` and `display: block`. You can also do things like this, which keeps the links visible to screen readers but not humans:

```
.hidden {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. But my main problem is when I expand my list these hrefs don't work. It instantly close this list without moving me to other page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fnv72sLu/ - I commented out the unnecessary stuff. Note, there are other problems which are beyond the scope of this question, please don't ask further questions here - open a new question instead.

Comment: If you add `.sub-menu:hover { display: block }` in there, it fixes one of your problems. https://jsfiddle.net/od9xpqjn/

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and advice about using this forum.

Answer (score 0):

By default, selector `pointer-events: none` should have rule `.sub-menu` set.

Even with focus, tags `a` continue to be inactive. Add rule `pointer-events: auto` for the `.sub-menu:hover ul li a` selector.

```
.sub-menu:hover ul li a {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

li.position {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: powderblue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.sub-menu ul li a {
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li a:focus + .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.sub-menu:hover ul li a {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">click here</a>

        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="position"><a href="https://amazon.com" class="padding">amazon</a></li>
                <li class="position"><a href="https://amazon.com" class="padding">amazon</a></li>
                <li class="position"><a href="https://amazon.com" class="padding">amazon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```